# Equalizer subgroup of a direct sum with respect to two natural surjections onto a modular arithmetic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

Let $m,n, l \in \Bbb{N}$.  Consider the following commuting square of modular arithmetic groups:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Bbb{Z}/mnl @>f>> \Bbb{Z}/ml \\
@VgVV \ @Vf'VV \\
\Bbb{Z}/nl @>g'>> \Bbb{Z}/l
\end{CD}
$$

Where each map is the natural surjection.  What would be the subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/nl \oplus \Bbb{Z}/ml$ that equalizes $f'', g''$ where $f'' = f' \circ p_1$ and $p_1 : \Bbb{Z}/nl \oplus \Bbb{Z}/ml \to \Bbb{Z}/nl$ is the natural projection.  Similarly for $g'', p_2$.

**Attempt.** From [Wikipedia article on equalizer property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)#In_category_theory) if $e : E \hookrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/nl \oplus \Bbb{Z}/ml$ is the equalizer arrow, then for any $h: O \to \Bbb{Z}/nl \oplus \Bbb{Z}/ml$ is such that $f' \circ h = g' \circ h$ then there exists a unique map $u : O \to E$ such that $e \circ u = h$.

Let's try $E = \Bbb{Z}/mnl$ and $e = (f,g), e(x) = (f(x), g(x)) \in \Bbb{Z}/nl \oplus \Bbb{Z}/ml$.      Then clearly $f'' \circ e = f'' \circ p_1 \circ (f, g) = f' \circ f = g' \circ g = g'' \circ e$.  Let $O$ be another abelian group and $h : O \to \Bbb{Z}/nl \oplus \Bbb{Z}/ml$ be such that $f'' \circ h = g'' \circ h$.  But then by substitution, we have $f' \circ p_1 \circ h = g' \circ p_2 \circ h$.  So to define $u : O \to \Bbb{Z}/mnl$ we need $e \circ u = h$ or that $(f,g) \circ u = h = (f\circ u, g\circ u)$ which means $p_1 \circ h = f\circ u$ and $p_2 \circ h = g \circ u$.  And then what would come next?

Not sure if that was the right choice from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equalizer in question is $\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} / nl \oplus \mathbb{Z} / ml | f'(a) = g'(b)\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z} / nl \oplus \mathbb{Z} / ml$, since the forgetful functor $Group \to Set$ preserves equalizers. We have

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
\{(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} / nl \oplus \mathbb{Z} / ml | f'(a) = g'(b)\}
&= \{(\pi_{nl}(a), \pi_{ml}(b)) | a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, f'(\pi_{nl}(a)) = g'(\pi_{ml}(b))\} \\
&= \{(\pi_{nl}(a), \pi_{ml}(b)) | a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, \pi_l(a) = \pi_l(b)\} \\
&= \{(\pi_{nl}(a), \pi_{ml}(b)) | a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, a \equiv b \mod l\}
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}

And I think that's as simple as it gets.

Comment: Can we identify the group with anything, knowing $m,n,l$?  If not, then what if $n,m,l$ are all prime?